# Can humidity affect the display on my Macbook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, display

For the second time now on our annual trip to the Keys, my 2012 MacBook Air's display has gone blank and only flickers on occasionally. Same thing happened last year. The problem disappeared completely on our return to Michigan and had not resurfaced again until I returned to Florida. Another possibility is higher voltage here? Could it be a bad charger?

Comment: For the Charger question, just let it run on battery to check that. For the humidity question, use a hair fan (on cold) and blow at it for a while to check that. Do you actually see humidity condensation on your Mac ?

Comment: No, on the humidity issue. But thanks for the hairdryer tip! Everything seems to be running fine on battery alone today. I think I'm going with the charger as the culprit. If a charger is running properly it should regulate voltage, right? And maybe I won't let it sit on the charger overnight. Thanks SO much for responding!

Comment: you are welcome, I almost suggested a dryer climate like California or Arizona :). As for the charger, it could be it, but it is build to operate worldwide (100-240 Volts input and 50/60 Hz.

Comment: I went from -20 in Ann Arbor to 75 here. Drier climate would be nice but this is just fine! Thanks again.